# Get current speed of VoiceOver on iOS

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

Is there any way to get the current speed of the VoiceOver speech on an iOS app? Sometimes I use my own `AVSpeechUtterance` strings and I'd like to use the same rate that's is configured on VoiceOver settings. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any luck with this? I would also like to know how to get that

Comment: Sorry @DanutPralea. At this moment there isn't any method to get the current VoiceOver speed :(

Comment: yeah, that's what I figured as well

Comment: Hi. Is there any way to get this? I'm also looking to get the current voiceover voice. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm also looking for a solution for this.

Comment: I am also looking for this

Answer (score 3):

Is the announcement specifically for VoiceOver users? Then it might be better to post announcement notification from UIAccessibility. VoiceOver will announce the notification, so users will hear with the same voice and speed from their VoiceOver setting.

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification:.announcement, argument:"Hello World!")
```

Read more information from the documentation.

UIAccessibility.post: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1615194-post

UIAccessibility.Notification: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/notification

announcement: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/notification/1620176-announcement

Comment: This worked very well for me in conjunction with UIAccessibility.announcementDidFinishNotification in order to do something after VoiceOver finished speaking, without disrupting the user's set speaking rate setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use AVSpeechUtterance with VoiceOver settings, you can use this parameter `prefersAssistiveTechnologySettings` since iOS 14*

```swift
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello world !")
utterance.prefersAssistiveTechnologySettings = true
```

Note that it will use the VoiceOver settings only if VoiceOver is activated when the utterance is called.

From apple documentation for this parameter:

> If an assistive technology is on, like VoiceOver, the user's selected voice, rate and other settings will be used for this speech utterance instead of the default values.
> If no assistive technologies are on, then the values of the properties on AVSpeechUtterance will be used.
> Note that querying the properties will not refect the user's settings.

So you do not have access directly to the user settings but you can still use them.